# How to bolden the parentheses around issue number of an article in reference list while using apacite package?

Tags: cross-referencing, bold, apacite, number

I have tried using `\textbf` around the issue number but that bolds only the number itself and not parentheses around it. Tried `\bf` to bold the volume number and that worked.

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a4, 12pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{apacite}

\AtBeginDocument{

    
\renewcommand{\BBAA}{and} % to avoid use of & instead of 'and'

    \renewcommand{\BCBT}{} % to avoid oxford comma

        \renewcommand{\BCBL}{} % to avoid oxford comma 

}

 \begin{document}

%.... blah blah ....


 \bibliographystyle{apacite}

\bibliography{reference1.bib}

 \end{document}
```

I have this in the `.bib` file:

```
@article{author1, title={The paper on sports analytics}, volume={\bf{23}}, number={\textbf{456}}, journal={Journal of the sports analytics}, author={Lames, Jebron}, year={1990}, pages={789-123},}
```

Output is shown below. Parentheses around 456 need to be bold. I am using `\citeA` to refer to the citations and `apacite` package. I think I need to define a command like `\boldvolume` but I am not able to figure it out. Here is the package documentation [`apacite`](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf).

[image]

I would prefer not to edit the `.bst` file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `apa` is a complex citation style. If you really need it, do not modify it.  Also, it is a bad idea to clutter the bib file with formatting statements, as you do.

Comment: Rightly said, thanks Denis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the formatting command (and there is no need to add \bf or \textbf to the bib-entry). But imho this is bad typography. The volume and number is *not* the most important data in bib entry, and so marking it with a strong emphasis sends the wrong message.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, 12pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{apacite}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand{\BBAA}{and}% to avoid use of & instead of 'and'
\renewcommand{\BCBT}{}% to avoid oxford comma
\renewcommand{\BCBL}{}% to avoid oxford comma
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{%
  \Bem{#1}%             journal
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, \textbf{#2}%  volume bold
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
  \else
    \unskip\textbf{({#3})}%      issue number bold
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#4\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, {#4}%      pages
  \fi
}
\makeatother

 \begin{document}
\cite{author1}
%.... blah blah ....


 \bibliographystyle{apacite}

\bibliography{test.bib}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Several styles do make the volume number bold.

Comment: @egreg thanks for edit (and I know that this is done, but I do find it bad anyway, it sprinkles a bibliography with bold blobs nobody needs).

Comment: Thanks @egreg and Urlike Fischer! You guys are legends! This worked like a charm. I know it is against the norm to bolden the volume and issue numbers, but this particular journal wants it in this manner. I also think it is a very weird requirement for a journal to have.